# Unable to display Spinning wheel image after report source is binding

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services, reporting, rdlc

I' m using Reporting Services for my .net project reporting. Problem is i can not hide loading gif. How can i invisible loading image after data is binded.
[image]

I added ScriptManager and ReportViewer to aspx page.

```
 <td colspan="4">
                <table width="95%">
                    <tr>
                        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
                        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" SizeToReportContent="true" AsyncRendering="false" WaitControlDisplayAfter="1000"  ></rsweb:ReportViewer>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
```

Data is binded to reportviewer on button click.

```
  protected void btnShow__Click(object Sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReportManager manager = new ReportManager();

            int receiverCompanyId = -1;
            if (cboReceiverCompany.SelectedIndex > 0 && cboReceiverCompany.SelectedItem.Value != null)
                receiverCompanyId = cboReceiverCompany.SelectedItem.Value.AsInt();

            int year = -1;
            if (cboYear.SelectedIndex > 0 && cboYear.SelectedItem.Value != null)
                year = cboYear.SelectedItem.Value.AsInt();

            int month = -1;
            if (cboMonth.SelectedIndex > 0 && cboMonth.SelectedItem.Value != null)
                month = cboMonth.SelectedItem.Value.AsInt();

            ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/ReconcilationReport.rdlc");
            ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("ReconcilationDataSet", manager.GetReconcilationReportView(receiverCompanyId, year, month));
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);

            ReportViewer1.ShowWaitControlCancelLink = false;
            ReportViewer1.WaitControlDisplayAfter = 1000;
        }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I think OP is trying to hide the Loading gif, seen in first image.

Comment: Problem is loading gif. I want to hide it after data bind